# Scala- Databricks- Linear Regression

Tags: scala, linear-regression, databricks, categorical-data

Can someone please explain me the meaning of below line of code (in scala-databricks)

```scala
val categoricalIndexers = categoricalVariables
  .map(i => new StringIndexer().setHandleInvalid("skip").setInputCol(i)
                .setOutputCol(i+"Index"))
```

Comment: quick tip : use code fences to make the code more readable

Answer (score 1):

- The aim of the `StringIndexer` is to map a string column of labels to an ML column of label indices (see [the documentation of Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.StringIndexer.html) for more details and codes(.
- You can use `setHandleInvalid` to choose how the unseen labels are handled using the `StringIndexer`. If you choose the "skip" setting the rows containing the unseen labels will be skipped (removed from the output).
- And the aim of the end of the code `.setInputCol(i)` and `.setOutputCol(i+"Index")` is to index the string variables and to return the indexed variables; the names of the indexed variables are the names of the original string variables + "Index". For example, let's use the string variable "City". Once the string variable is indexed, the name of the indexed variable will be CityIndex.

You can use the following lines to index all the string variables of your data set :

```
var categoricalCols = DataSet.dtypes.filter(_._2 == "StringType").map(_._1) 

var indexOutputCols = categoricalCols.map(_ + "_Index")

// Handle string variables
var stringIndexer = new StringIndexer()
                        .setInputCols(categoricalCols)
                        .setOutputCols(indexOutputCols)
                        .setHandleInvalid("skip")
```

The indexed variables have the original name + "_indexed".